# load movie data from memory, then write to a movie file

Tags: macos, quicktime

Target: load movie data from memory, then write to a movie file on mac.

To do this, I found this:
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn1195/_index.html

part of my code is:

```
void createMovieFromMemory(void *data,
                       Size dataSize,
                       Str255 fileName)
{
    Handle myDataRef = NULL;

    MovieImportComponent    miComponent;
    Track                   targetTrack = nil;
    TimeValue               addedDuration = 0;
    long                    outFlags = 0;
    OSErr                   err;
    ComponentResult         result;
    Movie                   movie = NULL;


    miComponent = OpenDefaultComponent(MovieImportType,kQTFileTypeMP4); //kQTFileTypeWave

    //implementation of this is learned from the link given above
    myDataRef = createPointerDataRefWithExtensions(data, /* pointer to data */
                                                   dataSize, /* size of data */
                                                   fileName, /* file name */
                                                   0, /* file type */
                                                   nil); /* mime type */

    if (myDataRef)
    {
        OSErr err = noErr;
        short id = 0;

        err = MovieImportDataRef(miComponent,
                                 myDataRef,
                                 HandleDataHandlerSubType,
                                 movie,
                                 nil,
                                 &targetTrack,
                                 nil,
                                 &addedDuration,
                                 movieImportCreateTrack,
                                 &outFlags);        


        if (err == noErr)
            DisposeMovie(movie);

        DisposeHandle(myDataRef);
    }
}
```

Now my question is what is the correct way to load a movie in the memory (for testing purpose) and how should I arrange the movie data in the memory.

Currently, I load the movie to memory using the code below:

```
unsigned int getFileSize(FILE **file){
    unsigned int size;
    if(fseek(*file, 0, SEEK_END) == -1){ return -1; }
    size = ftell(*file);
    fseek(*file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return size;
}

char *getFileBuffer(FILE **file, unsigned int fileSize){
    char *buffer = malloc(fileSize + 1);
    fread(buffer, fileSize, 1, *file);
    return buffer;
}

unsigned int readFileToMemory(char path[], char **buffer){
unsigned int fileSize;

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(file != NULL){
        fileSize = getFileSize(&file);
        *buffer = getFileBuffer(&file, fileSize);
        fclose(file);
        return fileSize;
    }else{
        *buffer = NULL;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I tired it with code below:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    void* pData = NULL;
    Size iDataSize = 0;
    Str255 strFileName="/Users/x/SAMPLE_convert.mp4";

    char path[] = "/Users/x/SAMPLE.AVI";
    char *buffer;
    int fileSize;
    fileSize = readFileToMemory(path, &buffer);

    iDataSize = fileSize;

    createMovieFromMemory((void*)buffer,iDataSize,strFileName);
    return (0);
}
```

The function MovieImportDataRef() return error code -50. I searched around could not find error code -50. Any advices are welcome. Thanks.

JL

Answer (score 0):

You are using very old legacy APIs. To open a movie use NewMovieFromProperties():

```
    CFStringRef path = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, filename, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    Boolean boolTrue = TRUE;
    QTNewMoviePropertyElement newMovieProperties[] =
    {
        { kQTPropertyClass_DataLocation, kQTDataLocationPropertyID_CFStringNativePath,
            sizeof(CFStringRef), &path, 0 },
        { kQTPropertyClass_NewMovieProperty, kQTNewMoviePropertyID_Active,
            sizeof(boolTrue), &boolTrue, 0 },
        { kQTPropertyClass_MovieInstantiation, kQTMovieInstantiationPropertyID_AsyncOK,
            sizeof(boolTrue), &boolTrue, 0 },
        { kQTPropertyClass_NewMovieProperty, kQTNewMoviePropertyID_DontInteractWithUser,
            sizeof(boolTrue), &boolTrue, 0 },
        { kQTPropertyClass_MovieInstantiation, kQTMovieInstantiationPropertyID_DontAskUnresolvedDataRefs,
            sizeof(boolTrue), &boolTrue, 0 },
    };
    Movie movie = NULL;
    OSStatus err = NewMovieFromProperties(sizeof(newMovieProperties) / sizeof(newMovieProperties[0]), newMovieProperties, 0, NULL, &movie);
    CFRelease(path);
    if (err != noErr)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open movie (error %d)\n", err);
```

This will open a movie from a file. You can also open a movie from a URL. You say you want to open it from memory "for testing purposes" but this is more complicated as movie media data can potentially be huge and QuickTime is designed precisely NOT to load it all into memory but only access parts of the media as needed. If for some reason you really do have the data in memory the easiest way is probably to write to a file first.

Incidentally, although you don't say it you seem to be implying that you want to convert movies from one format to another (eg. AVI to MP4). NewMovieFromProperties will actually import a media file from any format that QuickTime supports (including AVI, MOV, MP4, WAV, 3GP, MP3, etc. not necessarily just movies but also audio files, still images, etc.) and create a QuickTime Movie structure in memory. You can then export using any available QuickTime movie exporter component to another format.

-50 is a parameter error (paramErr), see MacErrors.h in the CarbonCore framework.